# D3.JS Bubble Chart - reset chart when reducing circle size

Tags: jquery, d3.js

I am having some issues with a bubble chart, using D3.JS (https://d3js.org/).

I'm pretty sure that I just do not understand the library. Any hep would be appreciated

When I create a bubble chart and add an onclick event, via jQuery, to a circle to reduce its radius, the chart does not update. This leaves the circles with the same padding, as if the full size circle was still in place.

My question is, how do I reset or re-generate the chart so that the new size of the circles are used and no unsightly gaps remain?

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
  <meta name="googlebot" content="noindex, nofollow">
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="//rawgit.com/ngryman/jquery.finger/v0.1.2/dist/jquery.finger.js"></script>
  <title></title>
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[
$(document).ready(function () {
        var width = 700,
        height = 700,
        padding = 12,
        clusterPadding = 4,
        maxRadius = 36;

        var n = 17,
            m = 1;

        var color = d3.scale.category10().domain(d3.range(m));
        var clusters = new Array(m);

        var nodes = d3.range(n).map(function () {
            var i = m,
                r = 36,
                d = {
                    cluster: i,
                    radius: r,
                    name: "Label",
                    x: Math.cos(i / m * 2 * Math.PI) * 200 + width / 2 + Math.random(),
                    y: Math.sin(i / m * 2 * Math.PI) * 200 + height / 2 + Math.random()
                };

            if (!clusters[i] || (r > clusters[i].radius)) clusters[i] = d;
            return d;
        });

        var force = d3.layout.force()
            .nodes(nodes)
            .size([width, height])
            .gravity(0.52)
            .charge(0.02)
            .on("tick", tick)
            .start();

        var svg = d3.select("#bubbles").append("svg")
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", height);

        var node = svg.selectAll("circle")
            .data(nodes)
            .enter().append("g").call(force.drag);
                node.append("circle")
                .style("fill", '#efeeeb')
                node.append("text")
                .text(function (d) {
                    return d.name;
                })

            .text(function (d) {
                return d.name
            })
            .style("fill", "black");

        svg.on("click", function() {
          force.resume();
        });

        function tick(e) {
            node.each(cluster(0.5*e.alpha * e.alpha))
                .each(collide(0.25))
            .attr("transform", function (d) {
                var k = "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
                return k;
            })
        }

        // Move d to be adjacent to the cluster node.
        function cluster(alpha) {
            return function (d) {
                var cluster = clusters[d.cluster];
                if (cluster === d) return;
                var x = d.x - cluster.x,
                    y = d.y - cluster.y,
                    l = Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y),
                    r = d.radius + cluster.radius;
                if (l != r) {
                    l = (l - r) / l * alpha;
                    d.x -= x *= l;
                    d.y -= y *= l;
                    cluster.x += x;
                    cluster.y += y;
                }
            };
        }

        // Resolves collisions between d and all other circles.
        var ID=0;
        function collide(alpha) {
            var quadtree = d3.geom.quadtree(nodes);
            return function (d) {
                var r = d.radius + maxRadius + Math.max(padding, clusterPadding),
                    nx1 = d.x - r,
                    nx2 = d.x + r,
                    ny1 = d.y - r,
                    ny2 = d.y + r;
                quadtree.visit(function (quad, x1, y1, x2, y2) {
                    if (quad.point && (quad.point !== d)) {
                        var x = d.x - quad.point.x,
                            y = d.y - quad.point.y,
                            l = Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y),
                            r = d.radius + quad.point.radius + (d.cluster === quad.point.cluster ? padding : clusterPadding);
                        if (l < r) {
                            l = (l - r) / l * alpha;
                            d.x -= x *= l;
                            d.y -= y *= l;
                            quad.point.x += x;
                            quad.point.y += y;
                        }
                    }
                    return x1 > nx2 || x2 < nx1 || y1 > ny2 || y2 < ny1;
                });
            };
        }

            var SVG = document.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0]
            var children = SVG.childNodes;

            [].forEach.call(children, function (child) {
                if(child.nodeType === 1 && child.tagName == "g"){
                     child.setAttribute('class', 'normal');
                    child.setAttribute('id', 'g'+ID);
                    ID++;
                }
                $('#totalBubbles').val(ID);
            });

            // click event to change appearance of circle
            $('#bubbles').on('click', '.normal', function () {
                $(this).find('circle').css({ fill: "#ffcc00" });
                $(this).find('circle').attr('r', 34);
                force.resume();
              });

            // long press event to reduce circle size
                $('#bubbles').on('press', '.normal', function () {
                    $(this).find('circle').css({ fill: '#595959' });
                    $(this).find('circle').attr('r', 20);
                    $(this).find('text').css('font-size',"6px");
                });

        var labels = ["One",'Two','three','Four','Five','Six','Seven','Eight','Nine','Ten','Eleven','Twelve','Apple','Banana','Carrot','Onion','Beans'];

        var z=0;
        $('g').each(function () {
            $(this).find('text').html(labels[z]);
                    $(this).find('circle').attr('r', 36);
                    $(this).find('text').attr("text-anchor","middle").attr("alignment-baseline","central");
            z++;
        });
    });//]]>
</script>


</head>

<body>

    <div id='bubbles'></div>
https://jsfiddle.net/amkdhpst/
</body>

</html>
```

I have created a JSFiddle here: [JS FIddle](https://jsfiddle.net/amkdhpst/)

Many thanks for any pointers in advance

David

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet would be to use D3.js event handlers to manage the click event, and remove the jQuery click handlers altogether. I modified your var node to look like this:

```
var node = svg.selectAll("circle")
    .data(nodes)
    .enter().append("g").call(force.drag);
        node.append("circle")
        .style("fill", '#efeeeb')
        .on("click", function() {
            d3.select(this)
          .style("fill", '#ffcc00')
          .attr("r", 25)                  
        });
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/amkdhpst/1/)

Comment: Many thanks for the reply. I've tried your updated JSFiddle and using your code in my page, but the bubbles still take up their original size space. It seems to be faster and cleaner (and with out JQ) but it doesn't seem to encourage the chart to close-in after the bubble size changes :(

Comment: Ah, my mistake. I understood the question to be asking how to resize the circles on click, rather than how to resize the space that they take up. To reduce the space taken up you will have to rerun the force algorithm on click (e.g. call force.start() in the click callback). I think your custom cluster algorithm would need to take into account the size of the circles. It maybe that the out of the box force.charge() method is useful for your purposes - that might simplify things, without requiring your custom algorithm.